# Libraries to generate docx files (Open XML)

Tags: c#, docx

We need to generate docx documents from an asp.net mvc site. The documents will vary a great deal, but they are pretty basic - the only thing out of the ordinary is the need to include tables. The c# code that generates the documents will need to create similar html/css as well.  We don't have time to buy a commercial product for this.

Should we just read the spec and write some code to spit out the XML, or are there libraries available that would do the trick?

Edit: looks like Microsoft's Open XML library is an obvious choice, but does anyone have any experience with it?  And can anyone point to some sample code that uses it?

Comment: Czech out http://docx.codeplex.com/. BTW, I think you confused the word "time" with "money" here when you wrote this: "We don't have time to buy a commercial product for this."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this... http://openxmlwriter.codeplex.com/

codeplex.com has a lot of other libraries too.

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=openxml

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater

It makes it possible to create a template written in docx, that contains tags `Hello {name}`  tha will be replaced.

You also have the possibility to create tables by looping over the table columns.