# Sending data to MS Word from your program

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm trying to find a way to send data from my program to MS word.

For Example:
I Have a textbox or a string, By presing a button the Ms word application will start and I will see my textbox content/string in the MS Word application.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is:

1. the dumb way: using Word interop which is slow and error prone. Google it if you need.
2. The really dumb way: writing docx files by hand. You are in a world of pain.
3. The smart way: find some library which writes  a word document (docx) for you. See [Libraries to generate docx files (Open XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356025/libraries-to-generate-docx-files-open-xml)

Answer (score 0):

This a classic mail merge question. Take a look at the following links:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8788a2ce-ac72-4bde-a063-c293413dd39b/how-to-generate-word-document-programmatically-from-template-and-data?forum=oxmlsdk#16616f04-6e81-408f-9a7c-4e3e1a20340d
[http://forums.asp.net/t/2001285.aspx?Populating+from+XML+to+the+Word+document+having+content+control+using+Open+XML+SDK+2+0+in+asp+net+c+framework+3+5](http://forums.asp.net/t/2001285.aspx?Populating%20from%20XML%20to%20the%20Word%20document%20having%20content%20control%20using%20Open%20XML%20SDK%202%200%20in%20asp%20net%20c%20framework%203%205)